# save php form to javascript var array of objects

Tags: javascript, php

i am very new to javascript and php. I am working on a project, i am allready pulling data from the below js file.

```js
var arrApps = {apps: [  
    {"id": "1",
     "app": "Happy Horse", 
     "url": "www.happyhorse.com",
     "owner": "",
     "queue": "someone else",
     "notes": ""},
    
    {"id": "2",
     "app": "Lucky Horse", 
     "url": "",
     "owner": "",
     "queue": "Yours",
     "notes": ""}
]};
```

I have a form, code below:

```html
<form method="post" action="">

            <label for="appName">Application Name: <span class="required">*</span> </label>
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="appName" name="appName" value="" placeholder="Application Name" required="required" >
            <br>
            <label for="url">URL:</label>
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="url" name="url" value="" placeholder="Enter Application URL">
            <br>
            <label for="notes">Notes:</label>
            <br>
            <textarea id="notes" name="notes" placeholder="Anything else important about application" required=""></textarea>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmitArray">

        </form>
```

I am trying to use php to get the form data and save to the javascript file. it is not setup exactly like a json file, so i keep running into issues. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Since you've shown NOTHING of your php code, we can't help you.

Comment: please provide more details. furthermore, is there a reason why you dont use correct .json format?